# Is it possible to force usage of custom fonts for text rendering on a given web page?

Tags: javascript, rendering, html, custom-font

Is it possible to use Javascript or any other technology to force the rendering of text on a given web page with a custom font? Downloading the font as a resource is ok. In other words, one would/should not rely on fonts installed in the users' browser.

Has anyone tried this? Is it possible at all? If yes, how?

Comment: My head does look a little like a bottom. I think it's due to having two brains. Really, I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to _me_, which is important as I'm the person it was directed at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS has the `@font-face`.  I think this is what you are talking about...

> @font-face is a css rule which allows you to download a particular
>   font from your server to render a webpage if the user hasn't got that
>   font installed. This means that web designers will no longer have to
>   adhere to a particular set of "web safe" fonts that the user has
>   pre-installed on their computer.

Read more here: http://www.font-face.com/#lime_content

You can create your own fonts for embedding here

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it, but it is possible. Google has a whole bunch of fonts you can have the user load using javascript [http://www.google.com/webfonts#ChoosePlace:select](http://www.google.com/webfonts#ChoosePlace%3aselect)